# Display video call using PJSIP and SwiftUI in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, swiftui, pjsip

I am trying to render video using PJSIP but the video is not coming on video call. The audio call is working properly. On the click video call button, the Video opens above the Dial view.

As for now, when I tapped on the button for making the video call nothing was happening. We want when we tap on the button for making the video the camera view will be open and the video call will be start.

If any other view for video call it is also acceptable.

ObjectiveC PJSIP Implementation

```
    void on_call_media_state(pjsua_call_id call_id) {
    pjsua_call_info call_info;
    pjsua_call_get_info(call_id, &call_info);
    
    if (call_info.media_status == PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_ACTIVE) {
        pjsua_conf_connect(call_info.conf_slot, 0);
        pjsua_conf_connect(0, call_info.conf_slot);
        
        // Handle video stream connection
        for (unsigned mi = 0; mi < call_info.media_cnt; ++mi) {
            if (call_info.media[mi].type == PJMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO && call_info.media[mi].dir & PJMEDIA_DIR_DECODING) {
                NSLog(@"Video stream is active.");
                    displayWindow(call_info.media[mi].stream.vid.win_in);
            }
        }
    }
  }

void displayWindow(pjsua_vid_win_id wid)
{
#if PJSUA_HAS_VIDEO
NSLog(@"windows id : %d",wid);
int i, last;

i = (wid == PJSUA_INVALID_ID) ? 0 : wid;
last = (wid == PJSUA_INVALID_ID) ? PJSUA_MAX_VID_WINS : wid+1;
if(wid == PJSUA_INVALID_ID){
printf("MyLogger: displayWindow failed\n");
}else{
printf("MyLogger: displayWindow success\n");}
for (;i < last; ++i) {
    pjsua_vid_win_info wi;
    pj_status_t myStatus;
    myStatus = pjsua_vid_win_get_info(i, &wi);
//    if(myStatus != PJ_SUCCESS) pjsua_perror(THIS_FILE, THIS_FILE, myStatus);
    if (myStatus == PJ_SUCCESS) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                /* Add the video window as subview */
                VideoCallViewController *videoCallVC = [[VideoCallViewController alloc] init];
                UIView *parent = videoCallVC.view;
                UIView *view = (__bridge UIView *)wi.hwnd.info.ios.window;
                if (![view isDescendantOfView:parent]){
                    [parent addSubview:view];
                }
                if (!wi.is_native) {
                    /* Resize it to fit width */
                    view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, parent.bounds.size.width,
                                             (parent.bounds.size.height *
                                              1.0*parent.bounds.size.width/
                                              view.bounds.size.width));
                    /* Center it horizontally */
                    view.center = CGPointMake(parent.bounds.size.width/2.0,
                                              view.bounds.size.height/2.0);
                } else {
                    /* Preview window, move it to the bottom */
                    view.center = CGPointMake(parent.bounds.size.width/2.0,
                                              parent.bounds.size.height-
                                              view.bounds.size.height/2.0);
                }
            });
    }


    NSLog(@"Windows ID: %d", wid);
#else
    NSLog(@"Video not supported.");

#endif
}
}
```

SwiftUI View:
Connectivity with objective-C

```
@objc
class VideoCallViewController: UIViewController {
    let registerWithPJSIP = RegisterWithPJSIP.shared
    @objc func makeShipDetailsUI(_ name: String) -> UIViewController {
        let details = DialView(registerWithPJSIP: registerWithPJSIP)
        return UIHostingController(rootView: details)
    }
}
```

Dial View:

```
        HStack {
        // MARK: Voice Call
        Image(systemName: hasVideo ? "video.fill" : "phone.fill.arrow.up.right")
            .onTapGesture {
                if isAnyCallPanding{
                    errorMessage = "Can't place a new call while you're already in a call"
                    showToast = true
                }else if receiverID == ""{
                    errorMessage = "Please provide receiver ID"
                    showToast = true
                }else{
                    lastRecentCallID = self.$receiverID.wrappedValue
                    callManagerPJSIP.receiverID = self.$receiverID.wrappedValue
                    if callID == nil{
                        let uuid = UUID()
                        self.callID = uuid
                    }
                    incomingCalling.startCall(to: self.$receiverID.wrappedValue, hasVideo: hasVideo, callID: self.callID ?? UUID()) { status in
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.hasActivateCall = status
                            isAnyCallPanding = true
                        }
                    }
                    
                    
                }
            }
    }
```